# How to insert Multireference selections?

Tags: collections, insert, content-management-system, velo

I'm trying to insert user's selection of the checkbox into CMS collection "profileapplicants"

They then submit their selection after submiting the form via clicking on submit button.

The checkbox options are used from CMS collection sessionlocation.

Why does wixData.insert insert all other user values but not the checkbox options?

Code:

````
```import wixData from "wix-data";
import { session } from "wix-storage";


$w.onReady(function () {
  populateSessionCheckbox();

  $w("#checkboxGroupSessLocation").onChange((event) => {
    const selectedSessLocation = $w("#checkboxGroupSessLocation").value;
    console.log("selectedSessLocation", selectedSessLocation);
    session.setItem("selectedSessLocation", JSON.stringify(selectedSessLocation));
  });

});

$w("#buttonSubmit").onClick(function () {
    if($w("#uploadButton1").value.length > 0)
    {
$w('#uploadButton1').uploadFiles()
.then((uploadedFiles)=>{
    const uploadedFile = uploadedFiles[0];
    let imgurl = uploadedFile.fileUrl;
    const selectedSessLocation = $w("#checkboxGroupSessLocation").value;
    //  JSON.parse(session.getItem("selectedSessLocation") || "[]");

    let toInsert={
        "name":$w("#inputName").value,
        "email":$w("#inputEmail").value,
        "image": imgurl,
        "phoneNumber": $w("#inputPhone").value,
        "address": $w("#inputAddress").value,
        "about": $w("#textBoxAbout").value,
        "yearsInPractice": $w("#inputPractice").value,
        "professionalDegree": $w("#inputDegree").value,
        "additionalCredentials": $w("#inputCredentials").value,
        "services": $w("#textBoxServices").value,
        "sessionlocation-multireference": selectedSessLocation

        
    };

    wixData.insert("profileapplicants", toInsert)
    .then((results)=>{
    $w("#msg").text="Data Saved successfully";
    $w("#msg").expand();    
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        $w("#msg").text=err;
        $w("#msg").expand();
        
    });
})
    }
    else{
        $w("#msg").text="Please choose image";
        $w("#msg").expand();

    }
  });



async function populateSessionCheckbox() {
  try {
    const sessionQueryResult = await wixData.query("sessionlocation").find();
    console.log("query result ethnicity", sessionQueryResult);

    const sessionChoices = sessionQueryResult.items;
    const sessionCheckBoxOptions = sessionChoices.map((choice) => ({
      label: choice.sessionLocation,
      value: choice._id,
    }));

    $w("#checkboxGroupSessLocation").options = sessionCheckBoxOptions;
    console.log("Dropdown Options:", sessionCheckBoxOptions);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error populating dropdown", err);
  }
}```
````

Tried entering user values through form submission but checkbox selection that uses the CMS collection that is multireferenced in the profileapplicants CMS collection. All text based fields are able to be written in but the multireferenced fields.

Looked at the documentation, from what I could understand, I thought I could use insertReference but not sure if I made it work either.

````
```import wixData from "wix-data"; import { session } from "wix-storage";

$w.onReady(function () {
    populateSessionCheckbox();

    //   $w("#checkboxGroupSessLocation").onChange((event) => {
    //     checkBoxOptions = $w("#checkboxGroupSessLocation").value;

    //   });

});

// export function checkboxGroupSessLocation_change(event) { //       const selectedSessLocation = $w("#checkboxGroupSessLocation").value; //     // console.log("selectedSessLocation", selectedSessLocation); //     session.setItem("selectedSessLocation", JSON.stringify(selectedSessLocation)); //    // JSON.parse(session.getItem("selectedSessLocation") || "[]"); // } $w("#buttonSubmit").onClick(function () {
    if ($w("#uploadButton1").value.length > 0) {
        $w('#uploadButton1').uploadFiles()
            .then((uploadedFiles) => {
                const uploadedFile = uploadedFiles[0];
                let imgurl = uploadedFile.fileUrl;
                const hardCodedCheckboxOption = "9b44e848-bdf9-46ff-ba90-edaa96e0b97b";

                let toInsert = {
                    "name": $w("#inputName").value,
                    "email": $w("#inputEmail").value,
                    "image": imgurl,
                    "phoneNumber": $w("#inputPhone").value,
                    "address": $w("#inputAddress").value,
                    "about": $w("#textBoxAbout").value,
                    "yearsInPractice": $w("#inputPractice").value,
                    "professionalDegree": $w("#inputDegree").value,
                    "additionalCredentials": $w("#inputCredentials").value,
                    "services": $w("#textBoxServices").value,
                    "sessionlocation-multireference": [hardCodedCheckboxOption],

                };
                console.log("Session Location Multi-Reference:", toInsert["sessionlocation-multireference"]);

                wixData.insert("profileapplicants", toInsert)
                    .then((results) => {
                        console.log(results);
                        $w("#msg").text = "Data Saved successfully";
                        $w("#msg").expand();
                        addHardCodeToProfileApplicant();
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        $w("#msg").text = err;
                        $w("#msg").expand();
                    });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                $w("#msg").text = "Error uploading file: " + err;
                $w("#msg").expand();
            });
    } else {
        $w("#msg").text = "Please choose image";
        $w("#msg").expand();
    } });

const addHardCodeToProfileApplicant = () => {
    const slick = "0ba90935-c052-420c-b0d2-44767093da4b";
    const hardCodedCheckboxOption = "9b44e848-bdf9-46ff-ba90-edaa96e0b97b";
    wixData.isReferenced("profileapplicants", "sessionlocation-multireference", slick, hardCodedCheckboxOption)
        .then((result) => {
            let isReferenced = result;
            console.log("isReferenced", isReferenced);
            if (!isReferenced) {
                wixData.insertReference("profileapplicants", "sessionlocation-multireference", slick, hardCodedCheckboxOption)
                    .then(() => {
                        console.log("reference inserted");
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.error("Error inserting reference:", err);
                    });
            }
        }); };

async function populateSessionCheckbox() {
    try {
        const sessionQueryResult = await wixData.query("sessionlocation").find();
        console.log("query result session", sessionQueryResult);

        const sessionChoices = sessionQueryResult.items;
        const sessionCheckBoxOptions = sessionChoices.map((choice) => ({
            label: choice.sessionLocation,
            value: choice._id,
        }));

        $w("#checkboxGroupSessLocation").options = sessionCheckBoxOptions;
        console.log("Dropdown Options:", sessionCheckBoxOptions);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error populating dropdown", err);
    } }

```
````